# Ionic routing doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I've been working on my first app and I'm stuck on the routing on the application.

There are in total 4 templates (Login,Overzicht,Settings,Toevoegen)

First the login template needs to show up (Which I got working.) and when I press login, it'll either let it pass or stop it. If I click login it takes me to the other 3 tabs.

From that point on, It doesn't work anymore! I have the following line:
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

And it indeed goes back to /login everytime.

I'll paste my code below

controllers.js

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, LoginService, $ionicPopup, $state) {
$scope.data = {};

$scope.login = function() {
    LoginService.loginUser($scope.data.username, $scope.data.password).success(function(data) {
        $state.go('tab.toevoegen');
    }).error(function(data) {
        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'Login failed!',
            template: 'Please check your credentials!'
        });
    });
}
})
```

App.js

```
.controller("SettingsCtrl", function($scope, $stateParams, $ionicHistory){
$scope.goBack = function(){
$ionicHistory.goBack();
}
})


   .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {


 $stateProvider
 .state('login', {
  url: '/login',
  templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
  controller: 'LoginCtrl'
})
 // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
.state('tab', {
url: 'templates/tab',
abstract: true,
templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
})

 // Each tab has its own nav history stack:

.state('tab.toevoegen', {
 url: 'templates/toevoegen.html',
views: {
  'toevoegen': {
    templateUrl: '/toevoegen.html',
    controller: 'TodoCtrl'
  }
 }
 })

 .state('tab.overzicht', {
  url: 'templates/overzicht',
  views: {
    'tabs-overzicht': {
      templateUrl: '/overzicht.html',
      controller: 'TodoCtrl'
    }
  }
})

.state('tab.settings', {
url: '/templates/settings.html',
templateurl: '/settings.html',
controller: 'SettingsCtrl'
});

// if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

});
```

services.js

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

.service('LoginService', function($q) {
return {
    loginUser: function(name, pw) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var promise = deferred.promise;

        if (name == undefined && pw == undefined) {
            deferred.resolve('Welcome ' + name + '!');
        } else {
            deferred.reject('Wrong credentials.');
        }
        promise.success = function(fn) {
            promise.then(fn);
            return promise;
        }
        promise.error = function(fn) {
            promise.then(null, fn);
            return promise;
        }
        return promise;
    }
}
})
```

Login template

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-     scalable=no, width=device-width">
 <title></title>

 <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

 <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
 <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
-->

 <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
 <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

 <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
 <script src="cordova.js"></script>

 <!-- your app's js -->
 <script src="js/controller.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body ng-app="todo" ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
 <ion-view view-title="Login" name="login-view">
 <ion-content class="padding">
  <div class="list list-inset">
      <label class="item item-input">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-model="data.username">
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input">
          <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="data.password">
      </label>
  </div>
  <button class="button button-block button-calm" ng-click="login()">Login</button>
 </ion-content>
</ion-view>

</body>
</html>
```

tabs.html

```
 <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-active-positive">

 <!-- Dashboard Tab -->
 <ion-tab title="Add" icon-off="ion-ios-pulse" icon-on="ion-ios-pulse-strong" href="#/tab/toevoegen">
  <ion-nav-view name="tab-toevoegen"></ion-nav-view>
 </ion-tab>

  <!-- Chats Tab -->
 <ion-tab title="Overzicht" icon-off="ion-ios-chatboxes-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-chatboxes" href="#/tab/overzicht.html">
 <ion-nav-view name="tab-overzicht"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

 <!-- Account Tab -->
 <ion-tab title="Settings" icon-off="ion-ios-gear-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-gear" href="#/tab/settings">
<ion-nav-view name="tab-setttings"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>


</ion-tabs>
```

overzicht.html

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="tabs.overzicht">
      <ion-content>
        <div ng-show="shouldShowInkomsten.checked">
        <ion-list>
        <div class="item item-divider">
          <p class="dividerclass">Inkomsten</p>
        </div>
             <ion-item ng-repeat="info in inkomsten" id="testborder1">
             <ion-option-button class="button-dark" ng-click=Spliceinkomen($index);startAgain() >Delete</ion-option-button>
             <div class="inkomsten-content">
                {{info.Description}} <p class="swiper"><strong>{{ info.Value | currency: "€" : 2}}</strong></p><p class="dateaddedtext"><br />Added: {{ info.Date | date:'dd-MM'}}</p>
              </div>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
        </div>

         <!-- Uitgiften lijst-->
         <div ng-show="shouldShowUitgiften.checked" >

            <ion-list >
          <div class="item item-divider">
          <p class="dividerclass">Uitgiften</p>
        </div>
              <ion-item ng-repeat="info in uitgiften" id="cat">
                <ion-option-button class="button-dark" ng-click=Spliceuitgiften($index);startAgain()>Delete</ion-option-button>

               {{ info.Description }} <p class="swiper"><strong>{{info.Value | currency: "€" : 2}} </strong></p><p class="dateaddedtext"><br />Added: {{ info.Date | date:'dd-MM'}}</p>
             </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
          </div>

        <div class="item item-divider">
          <p class="dividerclass">Uitkomst</p>
        </div>
        <div class="list list-inset">
          <div class="item">
          <p>Uw rest saldo is: {{endOutcome}} </p>
          <strong>Maand: {{ info.date | date:'MM' }}</strong>
          <p>{{Cate}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ion-content>
  </script>
```

Your help would be really appreciated. :)

Thanks in advance!

EDIT 10:17 19-01-2016

All of my templates are stored in ~/templates

I think you suggest I would change the url to url:'/templates' and then t the templateUrl to templateUrl:'/overzicht' right?

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) { 

 $stateProvider 
.state('login', {
 url: '/login',
 templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
 controller: 'LoginCtrl'
 })
 // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
 .state('tab', {
 url: '/tabs',
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
 })

  // Each tab has its own nav history stack:

 .state('tab.toevoegen', {
 url: '/toevoegen',
 views: {
 'toevoegen': {
  templateUrl: 'templates/toevoegen.html',
 controller: 'TodoCtrl'
  } 
 }
 })

 .state('tab.overzicht', {
 url: '/overzicht',
 views: {
 'tabs-overzicht': {
  templateUrl: 'templates/overzicht.html',
  controller: 'TodoCtrl'
}
}
})

.state('tab.settings', {
url: '/settings',
templateurl: 'templates/settings.html',
 controller: 'SettingsCtrl'
});

// if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

});
```

Comment: Your tab urls would look like this if they worked `templates/tabtemplates/toevoegen.html` is that desired?

Comment: so the first url which I declare (url:templates/overzicht.html) and the templateUrl are stacked? I would need to declare in every .state the url (/templates) and then the templateurl would be (/overzicht.html)?

Comment: I'm not sure about how the ui router states change with the context being Ionic. However, in the normal world of UI router. You declare your urls like so. parent `url: /parent` then child `url: /child` and this will create the URL `/parent/child`. You have defined however, parent: `url: templates/tab` and child `url: templates/toevoegen.html`. So you would need to add prefixed `/` to the child and you can remove the `html`.